# WCF Erro - A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Estou tendo um problema na hora de usar o `HttpWebRequest`, a primeira vez que eu chamo o método para efetuar o envio de uma NF-e ao WebServices da Sefaz ele executa normalmente mas na segunda vez que tento enviar outra NF-e ele me gera o seguinte erro:

> A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS.

Mais se eu reinicio o WCF ele efetua o envio corretamente.

Segue abaixo o código que estou usando.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

string XMLRetorno = string.Empty;

Uri uri = new Uri(url);

WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
HttpWebRequest httpWR = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;

httpWR.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", metodo);
httpWR.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
httpWR.Accept = "aplication/xml";
httpWR.Method = "POST";
httpWR.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
httpWR.KeepAlive = true;
httpWR.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
httpWR.Proxy = webProxy;

httpWR.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlSoap).Length;
httpWR.ClientCertificates.Clear();
httpWR.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);

Stream reqStream = httpWR.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlSoap), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlSoap).Length);
reqStream.Close();
reqStream.Dispose();

WebResponse webResponse = httpWR.GetResponse();
Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(respStream);

XMLRetorno = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();
streamReader.Dispose();

return XMLRetorno;
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas pode ser que você esta mantendo a conexão aberta mesmo após o envio, tente alterar este flag `httpWR.KeepAlive` ele está como `true` coloque `false` e faça um teste.

Comment: @Lodi eu coloquei mais agora ele esta dando toda hora.